# Running iOS Simulator in a sandbox

Tags: macos, ios-simulator, sandbox

macOS Sierra, Xcode 8.2.

I want to run the Xcode iOS simulator in a sandbox so I can limit network connectivity for applications I'm testing.

[Based on what I saw here](http://www.mac-forums.com/os-x-apps-and-games/137389-block-applications-accessing-internet.html), I created a sandbox file like this:

```
(version 1)
(allow default)
(deny network*)
```

Then I ran the simulator like this: `sandbox-exec -f ~/Desktop/block_network.sb /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator`

It seems that this doesn't properly connect Simulator to whatever other processes are managing it. The sim launches but says the device can't be found, and running in Xcode just opens up a different simulator. I also see this error in my terminal: `CoreSimulatorService connection became invalid.  Simulator services will no longer be available.` Any ideas?

I also tried removing `(deny network*)` from the sb file so everything is allowed; same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is very much unsupported but the problem is most likely the mach ports needed are being blocked by the sandbox.

You can try:

```
(allow mach-lookup)
(allow mach-register)
(allow distributed-notification-post)
(allow file-read* (regex #";^/[^/]+/CoreSimulator/[^/]+$"))
```

Look at the logs for sandbox violations then add exceptions as needed.

Comment: Thanks, but it gives me the same errors when I append this to my sandbox file. There aren't any sandbox violations in  the log. Since it doesn't work even if I have no "deny" rules in the sandbox, it seems that just running it in a sandbox at all breaks it.

Comment: It's probably failing to find some files it needs since paths get re-rooted into the sandbox directory. You can check `fs_usage` to see what paths it is trying to access under the sandbox.

Comment: That makes sense, but looking at `fs_usage`, every line containing "Simulator", "Xcode", or "sandbox" was accessing things from `/`, not anything in `~/Library/Containers/[...]`,  where the sandbox root dirs are (I see iWork apps accessing that).